# Newtons scheme not converging

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I am trying to find the critical points of the following non-linear system 
$$\pmb{F}(\pmb{\Psi}) = -\tau\lVert\pmb{\Psi}\rVert_{\ell^1}\ln\pmb{\Psi}-\pmb{U}\pmb{\Psi}$$ 
where $\tau$ is temperature$, \pmb{\Psi}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\pmb{U}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is a matrix with entries $u_{i,j} = -\cos(\frac{4\pi}{N}(i-j))$, where N is the number of divisions of the interval $[0,2\pi]$. I have implemented Newtons method to solve this system but it is not converging.

I believe its to do with my initial conditions but I am unsure how I can go about determining them for this system.

Comment: did you try for small $N$? how did you implement the logarithm of a vector? without more details on what specifically is going wrong it is unlikely a helpful answer can be obtained.

Comment: Yes I have tried for N=1 and 2 and it doesn't converge. The logarithm of a vector I have just taken to be the natural logarithm of each component of the vector $\pmb{\Psi}$.

Comment: so is this the set of equations you want to solve for $\Psi$, in order to find the critical point? (your element-wise evaluation of the logarithm is unusual, this is why I ask) $$\psi_n=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N|\psi_i|\right)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^N u_{nj}\psi_j\right],\;\;n=1,2,\ldots N$$

Comment: Yes that what I am trying to do.

Comment: you say the $N=1$ solution fails, but it's a trivial $\psi_1=e^{1/\tau}$ --- how can that fail?

Comment: I found an error in my scheme and it does now converge for $N=1,2$ but anything larger and it does not converge.